# Looking for collection of protocol state machines

Tags: automata, reference-request, communication-protocols, protocols

I'm currently studying structural properties of network and control protocols and their relation to testing. I'm specifically interested in state machines. They would not need to cover the full behavior to be useful. For many protocols, prototypical state machines can be found online when specifically searching for them. But I'm looking for some kind of collection to browse through. I could not find something suitable yet and would be grateful for any references.